# Delete file from jars

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-scripting

I am trying to remove files with .RSA extensions from all the jars inside a folder and its subfolders to resolve the following error:

> signer information does not match signer information of other classes
> in the same package

Below is my script:

```
echo off 
For /R C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\ %%G IN (*.jar) do ( 
    Echo "%%~dpG"
    cd "%%~dpG"
    jar xvf "%%~nxG" META-INF/"%%~nG".RSA
    rem jar -xvf %%G
    echo "Before"
    DEL "%%~nG"/META-INF/"%%~nG".RSA
    echo "After"
    jar uvf "%%~nxG" META-INF/"%%~nG".RSA
    rmdir /S/Q META-INF
    rem Echo "%%~nxG"
)
```

Below is the console output:

```
ECHO is off.
extracted: META-INF/worlds-1.1.RSA
"Before"
Invalid switch - "META-INF".
"After"
adding: META-INF/worlds-1.1.RSA(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
```

After running the batch, I still do see the RSA files and the error persist. I tried `type > nul` as well instead of `DEL`, but didn't work.

Looks like its not deleting the RSA file as I see following on the console:

> Invalid switch - "META-INF".

Comment: Hello, I'm a little confused; due to lack of understanding on what you're referring to with jar, and rsa. So is `.rsa` a file in a folder named jars? Or is `jars` an extension as well? Or?

Comment: File names and paths should be fully quoted with a single set of qouotes.. `DEL "%%~nG/META-INF/%%~nG.RSA"`

Comment: Just updated my question. The jars have files with .RSA extension. I am trying to remove those files from the JAR's and updating the JAR's.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks! Does the same applies to `jar xvf` and `jar uvf` commands as well? Should be in single set of quotes as well?

Comment: I'm by far not an expert in this area, but don't you need to remove the Signature File (`.sf` files) as well to "unsign" a jar file?